# Azure ExpressRoute Gateway Zone Redundant Gateway ARM Tempate

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-vpn

I want to create a Zone-redudant ExpressRoute Gateway using ARM templates, however I always get this error below

```
"message": "Virtual network gateway Sku specified is not valid for gateway /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/NSPRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/ERGw
```

with DeploymentType CloudService. The allowed Skus are Standard,HighPerformance,UltraPerformance.",

The ARM template code I'm using is below...editor is VSCode

```
 {
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways",
    "name": "[parameters('ERgatewayName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', parameters('gatewayPublicIPName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways', parameters('gatewayName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways', parameters('localGatewayName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "ipConfigurations": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
            "subnet": {
              "id": "[variables('gatewaySubnetRef')]"
            },
            "publicIPAddress": {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('ERgatewayPublicIPName'))]"
            }
          },
          "name": "ERvnetGatewayConfig"
        }
      ],
      "gatewayType": "[parameters('ERgatewayType')]" ,
      "sku": {
          "name":"ErGw3AZ",
          "tier":"ErGw3AZ"
      }
    
    
    }
  }
```

Please what could be the issue here

Comment: Do you add a public IP address with a Standard PublicIpaddress SKU?  or change the SKU to one of Standard,HighPerformance,UltraPerformance?

Comment: @NancyXiong thanks the public IP was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/about-zone-redundant-vnet-gateways#pipskus) stated:

> Zone-redundant gateways and zonal gateways both rely on the Azure
> public IP resource Standard SKU. The configuration of the Azure public
> IP resource determines whether the gateway that you deploy is
> zone-redundant, or zonal. If you create a public IP resource with a
> Basic SKU, the gateway will not have any zone redundancy, and the
> gateway resources will be regional.

for the error message, the public IP was the issue. We need to have a public IP resource Standard SKU for Zone-redundant gateways.